# Send data through the QueryString with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I want to send a string to another page named Reply.aspx using the QueryString.

I wrote this code on first page that must send the text to Reply.aspx:

```
protected void FReplybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String s = "Reply.aspx?";
    s += "Subject=" + FSubjectlbl.Text.ToString();
    Response.Redirect(s);
}
```

I wrote this code on the Reply.aspx page:

```
RSubjectlbl.Text += Request.QueryString["Subject"];
```

But this approach isn't working correctly and doesn't show the text.

What should I do to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: that code should work... What part goes wrong? Does the redirect occur correctly?

Comment: Does it show anything? You could htmlencode it so its a valid querystring. Or you could cache it in the session object if its on the same site.

Comment: the reply page is to a folder whit name ADMIN

Comment: Ok, And is the page doing the redirect also in that folder?

Comment: I don't know, this page is in the folder whit name ADMIN and now I change code but doesn't work yet .

String s = "~ADMIN/Reply.aspx?";
        s += "Subject=" + FSubjectlbl.Text;
        Response.Redirect(s);

Comment: Is it possible that FSubjectlbl.Text contains invalid characters (spaces, ampersands, etc.) that need to be sanitized first? Please post the value of "s" when the redirect occurs. Thanks!

Comment: @rdkleine- I think you mean Server.UrlEncode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is easy :

First page :

```
string s = "~/ADMIN/Reply.aspx?";
s += "Subject=" + FSubjectlbl.Text;
Response.Redirect(s);
```

Second page :

```
RSubjectlbl.Text = Request.QueryString["Subject"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Though your code should work fine, even if the source string has spaces etc. it should return something when you access query string, please try this also:

```
protected void FReplybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String s = Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/ADMIN/Reply.aspx");
    s += "?Subject=" + Server.UrlEncode(FSubjectlbl.Text.ToString());
    Response.Redirect(s);
}
```

EDIT:-

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.QueryString.HasKeys())
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Subject"]))
        {
            RSubjectlbl.Text += Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Subject"]);
        }
    }
}
```

PS:- Server.UrlEncode is also sugested in comment to this question.